# How can I block users with Windows Live Messenger?

Tags: blocking, windows-7, windows-live-messenger

Silly me: I installed Windows 7. Of course it breaks tons of things. Now for another basic how-to question for an essential function that the Microsoft Newbies seemed to remove.

I am getting spamed by a user that's not on my contact list. It will send me messages every few hours. I want to BLOCK this user. How?

If they're not in my contact list I can't say "block". When I go tools -> options there's no block list anymore.

So I've got to add the spammer so I can block them?

Comment: same here..im getting same message for same spammer everyday..how the hell do u block

Answer (score 1):

Since the user is not in your contacts' list you can't open the chat window with that user, the next time he sends to you a message click on "block and report" for you to block him and you be removed from his contact list.

Comment: Nope - no such button on Windows Live Messenger on Windows 7. Invalid answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but no access to another computer so i logged on using a web messenger (like ebuddy) and was able to block the spammer from there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

My solution: log in on a different computer, that has NOT Windows 7, but has MSN (almost any version) installed. The spammer eventually bugs you there, but this time you can take revenge on him by pushing the BLOCK button.